# Why does foreach combine with cbind on one element return a vector not a matrix?

Tags: r, foreach

```
foreach(i=seq_len(1), .combine = cbind) %do% c(1,2,3)
```

gives the numeric vector `c(1,2,3)`, whereas to be consistent with other sequence lengths it should give a 3x1 matrix. In particular

```
cbind( c(1,2,3) )
```

gives a matrix, not a vector. Why is this?

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism to those who labelled this as primarily opinion-based, rather than the original two downvotes who didn't say why they were down-voting. I've edited the question, hopefully that helps a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry this should probably be a comment rather than an answer, but I can't yet comment, so it's here to address your question. I would say it's not a bug. The cbind in the foreach is doing something different. It's combining the results between iterations, but you only have one in your original statement so there's nothing to cbind.

```
foreach(i=seq_len(1), .combine = 'cbind') %dopar% c(1,2,3)
```

yields your result:

```
[1] 1 2 3
```

but if there's more than one iteration,

```
foreach(i=seq_len(2), .combine = 'cbind') %dopar% c(1,2,3)

     result.1 result.2
[1,]        1        1
[2,]        2        2
[3,]        3        3
```

properly combined between iterations with cbind. If you absolutely must in just one round, then the cbind would have to move into the statement

```
foreach(i=seq_len(1)) %dopar% cbind( c(1,2,3) )
[[1]]
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
```

and note that as per the documentation, the result is returned as a list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm aware that if the sequence is longer than length 1 I get a matrix. My actual problem is that this is an inner loop where the sequence lengths vary: with the way this works currently I would have to  handle length==1 as a special case.

Comment: NP. gotcha. pesky then. Yes, wrapping a conditional for the special case is the only alternative I can think of - as far as I've read, there's no between-iteration equivalent of a `drop=F` type of argument

Comment: Yeah, it reminds me a lot of the drop=F issue. Even if it's not very satisfying I gave you an upvote for bothering to look at it instead of just downvoting the question (whoever that was!).